# Error with bundle identifier "org.cocoapods.device-id" at App Store Connect validation

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight, flutter-dependencies

I'm getting following error, when i try to upload my Flutter IOS app to TestFlight:

> **Invalid Code Signature Identifier. The identifier**
>   **"org.cocoapods.device-id" in your code signature for "device-id" must**
>   **match its Bundle Indentifier "flutter.myAPP.app1".**

I have created app with Bundle Indentifier "flutter.myAPP.app1" at developer.apple.com. My app uses pods as on image.

[image: My runner ipa content looks as follows]

Thank you all in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed device_id package from my code. Apparentaly it is not supported any longer with newer IOS platform. What fixed issue.